# Store JSignature output to mysql to be redrawn on separate page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Can someone please explain to me exactly how to take the output of my JSignature form and store it in my MySQL database so I can get the stupid thing to redraw on another page later? I swear I feel like such a total idiot sometimes. Please keep in mind that I know very little about Javascript and will likely need someone to walk me through this step by step.

OK so, I have gotten the JSignature working on my page with the following code:

```
<div id="signatureparent">
    <div id="signature"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="$('#signature').jSignature('clear')">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert($('#signature').jSignature('getData','base30'))">Save</button>
</div>
<div id="scrollgrabber"></div>
<script src="jsig/src/jSignature.js"></script>
<script src="jsig/src/plugins/jSignature.CompressorBase30.js"></script>
<script src="jsig/src/plugins/jSignature.CompressorSVG.js"></script>
<script src="jsig/src/plugins/jSignature.UndoButton.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $sigdiv = $("#signature").jSignature({'UndoButton':false})
    })
</script>
```

This is all within a form that is submitting a bunch of data via $_POST.

As you can see, I have added a button that will display the output to any alert window but I have no clue as to how to place that value inside a hidden input so it can be submitted with the rest of my form.

Thank you to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funky plugin.

```
<div id="signatureparent">
<div id="signature"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="$('#signature').jSignature('clear')">Clear</button>
<button type="button" id="btnSave">Save</button>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenSigData" name="hiddenSigData" />
<div id="scrollgrabber"></div>
<script src="jsig/src/jSignature.js"></script>
<script src="jsig/src/plugins/jSignature.CompressorBase30.js"></script>
<script src="jsig/src/plugins/jSignature.CompressorSVG.js"></script>
<script src="jsig/src/plugins/jSignature.UndoButton.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $sigdiv = $("#signature").jSignature({'UndoButton':false});

        // -- i explain from here...
        $('#btnSave').click(function(){
            var sigData = $('#signature').jSignature('getData','base30');
            $('#hiddenSigData').val(sigData);
        });
        // -- ... to here.

    })
</script>
```

That snippet of code above says:
1. "when the button with the id 'btnSave' is clicked"...
2. Convert the signature canvas to a bas64 encoded string, and save it in a variable called 'sigData'.
3. Set the value of the field with id 'hiddenSigData' to variable 'sigData'.

Boom, you have it.

Do you have any server-side code for processing your form? I've assumed that you're using `<form>` tags... that field will then just appear with the POST'ed data.

If you don't have any handler for the data, you'll need to look into C#/PHP depending on what you're running. But, anyway.. that's the JS bit.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't have time to test it just yet but I'm sure it will work. That's all I needed.

I do have the form submitting to the database using POST. I'm not bad with PHP just javascript. Thanks again!

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm. There was an extra character in your syntax that would break the form: id="btnSave")"> but I removed it and it all works! I even got it saving to the database. Now tomorrow, I work on re-displaying the signature FROM the database!

Comment: Glad it helped - and edited the ) out, thanks!  For SETTING it, you need to retrieve that string from the DB, and will want to do something like `$('#signatureField').jSignature("importData",stringFromDb)`...  just to ruin your fun for tomorrow... ;).